# Is it possible to use an external application (or at least its settings) when capturing the live camera on OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to configure the camera parameters from the application on the pc and be able to use those directly on OpenCV when capturing the live video stream. Is it possible to use the external application for capturing the camera?

Comment: Depends on camera model you are using. If opencv backed doesn't support your camera api, you cant change it. Better way is using camera api to change configuration

Comment: Agree with @YunusTemurlenk The other possibility is 
1. the camera has an internal memory for storing the settings and make them as default values at startup
2. the external application you're using, allows to modify and store configuration in this camera memory
then you would be able to use the same settings in your opencv appllication

Comment: on windows with DSHOW, by calling `cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_SETTINGS, 0)`, you can pop up a settings dialog. otherwise... no. depends on the API that is used and if the camera retains anything (again depends on API).